# How to convert Hex value to acceptable uint (possibly number) using typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I have looked at quite a few examples and I have had no real luck. The problem I am facing, is that I need to pass a Hex value in an acceptable uint value using typescript. The value that I need to convert to a hex value is -15921907 however I have more success converting that to rgb, but even then it is not 100% accurate. and then I need to convert a hex value to a similar value as the one metnioned.

Is there any hope for this or is it a lost cause due to the limited functionality in Typescript?

Thanks in advance for any help. if there is anything that I can provide to aid in this being resolved, please let me know =) (in case my explanation does not make any sense, also let me know...)

I am going to keep looking for a solution and will post when I have found it, any form of idea or anything will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `number.toString(16)` to yield hex and `parseInt(hexnumber, 16)` to convert it back.  I don't know if you've tried that or not.

```js
const decimalNumber = 12456
const hexNumber = '0x30a8'
console.log('DecToHex:  ' + decimalNumber.toString(16))
console.log('HexToDec:  ' + parseInt(hexNumber, 16))
```